# Immidiately update label text property

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I wonder if I can immidiately update a property of a Label described in a kv layout file as so:

```
    BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    Label:
        id: new_order
        font_size: 40
        text: ''
```

Thats because in my app I have set up two Clock schedule interval objects and I wont them to work simultaneously.

```
class MyApp(App):
   def on_start(self):
       Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_label, 1)
       Clock.schedule_interval(self.play_sounds, 1)

  def update_label(self):
     # does something
     self.root.ids.new_order.text="Updated Text"
     # does something more

  def play_sounds(self):
     for i in range(10):
         sound.play()
         sleep(2)
```

But... label is always updated after the play_sounds() method exits. So is there a way to immidiately update the displayed label text just after setting it to "Updated Text" inside update_label() method?

Comment: I'm not a pro so my "system D" solution would be to always check the `self.root.ids.new_order` text that is display on the `play_sounds` method and to trigger my `sound.play()` only if it's ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have done and solved my problem, was to spawn a thread to handle sound-playing in parallel with main, after the helpful @john-anderson answer. So:

```
import Threading
def play_sounds():
  for i in range(10):
      sound.play()
      sleep(2)

class MyApp(App):
   def on_start(self):
       Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_label, 1)

  def update_label(self):
     # if condition:
         self.root.ids.new_order.text="Updated Text"
         t = threading.Thread(target=play_sounds)
         t.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `play_sounds()` method will take at least 20 seconds to run (because of the `sleep`) and you are trying to run that method every second. Sounds like a bad idea. Also, the `sleep` freezes your entire GUI, since it is run on the main thread. Try changing `play_sounds()` to:

```
def play_sounds(self, dt):
    sound = SoundLoader.load('some_sound_file')
    sound.play()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could nest the `Clock.schedule_interval`. Within the function after the main logic body of the function, you could put in another `Clock.schedule_interval` with the next function to call. I recommend in the inner function that you use a clock [lambda function](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html) to create a one liner.